# Chaining Keras Models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a Keras model classifier with multiple classes. I want my model to output the class names along with the class probabilities. I tried to modify this [example](https://towardsdatascience.com/customize-classification-model-output-layer-46355a905b86) which creates a custom layer and a second model that takes the output of the first model as input. However, it `fits` the first model separately.

Is there a way to do this chaining so that I can just return the second model and compile it so it will fit both?

Here is the label layer code.

```python
class LabelLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  """Custom layer that outputs labels along with scores."""

  def __init__(self, labels, **kwargs):
    super(LabelLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.labels = labels

  def call(self, scores):
    batch_size = tf.shape(scores)[0]
    labels_tensor = tf.constant([self.labels], dtype='string')
    labels_tensor = tf.tile(labels_tensor, [batch_size, 1])
    return [scores, labels_tensor]

  def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return [input_shape, input_shape]

  def get_config(self):
    config = {'label_layer_labels': self.labels}
    base_config = super(LabelLayer, self).get_config()
    return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

The following works if I fit the base model first.

```
base_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
base_model.compile(
      loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
      optimizer='adam',
      metrics=['accuracy'])
base_model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    epochs=num_epochs,
    batch_size=batch_size)

label_layer = LabelLayer(label_names)(model.output)
label_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=label_layer)

return label_model.predict(x_test)
```

However, I just want to return the label_model itself so that the consumer can just fit one model and doesn't need to know about the base_model.

I tried this which didn't work.

```python
base_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
base_model.compile(
      loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
      optimizer='adam',
      metrics=['accuracy'])

label_layer = LabelLayer(label_names)(model.output)
label_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=label_layer)
label_model.compile(
      loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
      optimizer='adam',
      metrics=['accuracy'])
label_model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    epochs=num_epochs,
    batch_size=batch_size)

return label_model.predict(x_test)
```

The above doesn't work, which isn't a surprise. What is the fix here? To create a custom model that subclasses a keras model and overrides the behavior of fit and compile? As I only need to fit and compile the base_model.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get something working with the following. It feels like a hack so I am still interested in other solutions.

This basically just delegates fit and compile to the base model.

```python
class LabelModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, base_model, labels, **kwargs):
    super(LabelModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.labels = labels
    self.base_model = base_model
    self.label_layer = LabelLayer(labels)(base_model.output)
    self.label_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=base_model.inputs, outputs=self.label_layer)

  def call(self, inputs):
    return self.label_model(inputs)

  def compile(self,
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss=None,
              metrics=None,
              loss_weights=None,
              weighted_metrics=None,
              run_eagerly=None,
              steps_per_execution=None,
              **kwargs):
    self.base_model.compile(optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights,
                            weighted_metrics, run_eagerly, steps_per_execution,
                            **kwargs)

  def fit(self,
          x=None,
          y=None,
          batch_size=None,
          epochs=1,
          verbose=1,
          callbacks=None,
          validation_split=0.,
          validation_data=None,
          shuffle=True,
          class_weight=None,
          sample_weight=None,
          initial_epoch=0,
          steps_per_epoch=None,
          validation_steps=None,
          validation_batch_size=None,
          validation_freq=1,
          max_queue_size=10,
          workers=1,
          use_multiprocessing=False):
    return self.base_model.fit(x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
                               validation_split, validation_data, shuffle,
                               class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch,
                               steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
                               validation_batch_size, validation_freq,
                               max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
```